# Place Div directley under a text box

Tags: html, css

I am having a few problems with placing a Div directly under a text box with CSS. I need the Div directly under the text box using preferably only CSS/CSS3 Transitions. I have tried what I know, But all attempts have seem to fail. If anyone can help me out, I'll be greatfull.

Picture 1 is how I am trying to place the Div, and Picture 2 is how it is now:  http://i49.tinypic.com/2h31zjp.jpg

**CSS:**

```
input {
  top:18px; left:20px;
  width:1230px; padding:4px;
  border:1px dashed grey;
  font:16px arial;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#d8d8d8;
}

input:focus+p {
  height:200px;
}

p {
  overflow:hidden;
  height:0;
  width:1230px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border:1px dashed gray;
  transition:height.5s;
  -moz-transition:height 0.5s;
  -o-transition:height 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition:height 0.5s;
}
```

Comment: Impossible for us to help without seeing your html & css. Would be good if you could post on jsfiddle.net or similar.

Comment: any css that you have written?

Comment: @James Post some code or markup.

Comment: Remove padding/margin on your text box element (or possibly the element containing the text box) and the problem should go away.

Comment: for sure gap is caused by margin if you have not positioned your elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to place the `<input>` first, then the `<div>`. The div can be pushed down using a line break `<br>`. Since input has a default border by itself, done by browsers, there is a chance for the change in appearance in multiple browsers. So you have to define a solid border for your `<input>`, say like one with 1px. You may also define `margin: 0` and `padding: 0` in your `html` or `body` or your parent container.

***[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/AmdAc/)*** is a live demo what you are asking for.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just add few lines in your answer to explain it to the question poster.

Answer (score 0):

Check margins and padding of div element and margins of text element. It should all be 0 to achieve all you want.

Comment: I believe this is the answer for the question either way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
input{

     font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#900    ;
     background-color:#CCC; width:100%
}
p{
    padding:0;
     margin:0;
    width:100%;
    height:150px;
    border:#063 dotted 2px;
    background-color:#9C3   
}


<input name="" type="text" />
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be because you given padding:4px; to input. Replace it to 0px;